# In a ruby .gemspec file, how do I specify multiple versions of a dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I'm trying to modify a gem which currently has a dependency on activeresource defined as:

```
s.add_dependency              "activeresource", "~> 3.0"
```

In order to get the gem working with Rails 4, I need to extend the dependency to work with either version 3 or 4 of activeresource. I don't want to simply add the following as it could cause problems later:

```
s.add_dependency              "activeresource", ">= 3.0"
```

Is there a way to specify a list of acceptable versions? ~> 3.0 or ~> 4.0?

Comment: I would personally say pick one and stick with it

Comment: `s.add_dependency "activeresource", ">= 3.0", "< 5.0"` is simplest I can think of. Of course you will need to detect when version is loaded and abstract differences away in the gem, which could be hard. I'd say just start a new major version of the gem and use the later dependency in it. You can still support both versions by releasing minor updates in parallel (if you really care to do so), but you won't pollute your code with run-time determinations of which `activerecord` engine you are working with

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accordly to [the documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic_version_constraint), if you want to have all version between 3 and 4, you can do this :

```
s.add_dependency "activeresource", ">= 3.0", "< 5.0"
```

The specifier accepted are : `>=, ~>, <=, >, <`.

Comment: How about `s.add_dependency "activeresource", ">= 3.0", "< 5.0"` ?

Comment: There is an additional specifier `!=` to exclude (buggy) versions

Answer (score 3):

I think you should write it with `< 5.x`, because this will prevent beta versions like `5.0.beta1` to be installed.

```
 s.add_dependency "activeresource", ">= 3.0", "< 5.x"
```

Because with `< 5.0`, `5.0.beta1` can be installed - `5.0.beta1` is smaller than `5.0`.