# public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.3 while installing fastlane

Tags: ruby, fastlane

Getting following error `public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.3.` while installing fastlane

i am using ruby 3.0

```
ruby -v 
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]
```

Installing fastlane

```
sudo gem install fastlane
```

getting below error

```
ERROR:  Error installing fastlane:
public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.3.
```

Comment: try sudo ruby -v

Comment: Running Ruby with sudo will certainly run a different version than without.

Comment: sudo ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: how i can upgarde this ?

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/weppos/publicsuffix-ruby/blob/v4.0.6/public_suffix.gemspec#L23

specifies that public_suffix requires a ruby version >= 2.x - so I believe that it will not, unfortunately, permit 3.x as a dependency.

See [In a ruby .gemspec file, how do I specify multiple versions of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523687/in-a-ruby-gemspec-file-how-do-i-specify-multiple-versions-of-a-dependency)

This is something that needs to be done by the gem maintainer.  It's also a fanstastic example of dependency hell in the wild.

Comment: `>= 2.3` does not restrict installation with 3.x, and I just tested to be sure. OP's issue is probably linked to `sudo` not looking up the same environment

Comment: @Geoffroy ah, interesting.  Just saw this elsewhere too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775795/fastlane-nokogiri-requires-ruby-version-2-3-0-error?rq=1 - which seems to back your hypothesis.

Comment: just try to install the gem and it won't be an hypothesis anymore :) You made me doubt so I had to try :)

Comment: @Geoffroy I don't have ruby 3.x installled locally and don't feel like waiting 20+ minutes for this useless work laptop to download and build it :D